# Valgrind no eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

já faz tempo que procuro e não encontro nada do tipo. Estou precisando usar o Valgrind no eclipse (eclipse possui suporte), eu já realizei todas as instalações de pacotes que encontrei na net mas não consegui de forma alguma rodar ele. Para executar eu vou em "PROFILING TOOLS -> PROFILE WITH VALGRIND" o projeto é compilado porem ele não roda junto com o valgrind. Segue a tela que aparece após o procedimento, que no caso seria para estar rodando o projeto com o valgrind.

[image: Apenas aparece essa mensagem e ele não roda]

Segue as configurações do valgrind:

[image: Configuração]

Alguém saberia onde estar o erro? ou qual configuração falta?

Answer (score 1):

Já obtive a solução, o problema foi decorrente de um pacote que faltava. O projeto roda em 32 bits e o valgrind estava selecionado para rodar em 64 bits. Basta apenas instalar o seguinte pacote:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386`